# How can I get Appium to scroll to an Element it can't find in iOS

Tags: java, ui-automation, cucumber-jvm, appium-ios

I am developing an automation test suite in Java using Appium 2, TestNG, and Cucumber.

I am currently facing an issue where I am trying to scroll to down a XCUIElementTypeTable until a particular XCUIElementTypeCell is visible then click on the cell.

For all my test that require scrolling to an element I have been using this method

```java
public void scrollElementIntoView(WebElement element) {
    driver.executeScript("mobile: scrollToElement", 
        ImmutableMap.of("element", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId()));
}
```

This works 99% of the time. However, if the screen/list is particularly long I keep getting `NoSuchElementException`. Even Appium Inspector fails to find the element sometimes.

How can I rework my scrollElementIntoView() method to avoid this issue?

Here is a censored(due to NDAs)version of the actual test that is failing.

**list-test.feature**

```
Scenario: App Item to List and verify it is present
    Given: App is open and user is logged in
    When: User navigates to Item List
    And: User adds new Item "itemName" to List
    Then: User can see new Item "itemName" listed #this step fails
```

**Stepdefs.java**

```java
@Then("User can see new Item {string} listed")
public void userSeeItem(String itemName){
    Assert.assertTrue(listPage.isItemListed(itemName));
```

**ListPage.java**

```java
public class ListPage {
    public AppiumDriver driver;
    public DriverHelper driverHelper;

    public MyPhonePage(AppiumDriver driver) {
            this.driver = driver;
            this.driverHelper = new DriverHelper(driver);
            PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }

    private WebElement listedItem(String itemName){
        return driverHelper.findElementWithWait(AppiumBy.xpath(String.format(
            "//XCUIElementTypeCell[@label='%s']", itemName))); // findElementWithWait() is where the error is thrown
    }

    public boolean isItemListed(itemName){
        driverHelper.scrollElementIntoView(listItem(itemName));
        return driverHelper.isElementVisible(listItem(itemName));
    }
}
```

**DriverHelper.java**

```java
public DriverHelper{
    AppiumDriver driver;
    private static final Duration WAIT = Duration.ofSeconds(15);

    public DriverHelper(AppiumDriver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public WebElement findElementWithWait(By by) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, WAIT);

        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by));
            return driver.findElement(by);
        } 
        catch (TimeoutException e) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException(String.format("The element with locator %s 
                was not located within 15 seconds.", by));
        }
    }

    public void scrollElementIntoView(WebElement element) {
        driver.executeScript("mobile: scrollToElement", 
            ImmutableMap.of("element", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId()));
    }

    public boolean isElementVisible(WebElement element){
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, WAIT);
        
        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(
                ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)));
            return true
        } 
        catch (TimeoutException e) {
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're working on some cool automation using Appium, TestNG, and Cucumber – that's awesome!

So, you're trying to scroll down a long list in your iOS app until you find a specific item to interact with, right? You're using the scrollElementIntoView() method, which usually works like a charm, but it's misbehaving when the list gets extra long. Not cool!

You're on the right track with your approach. The issue seems to stem from the findElementWithWait() method, where you're setting a wait time and trying to locate an element. If it's taking longer than your wait time, it throws a NoSuchElementException. Got it.

You could consider increasing the wait time in the DriverHelper class – maybe to 30 seconds or so – especially for those longer lists. This can give the system more time to find the element, especially in cases where the list is extensive.

Alternatively, you could try catching StaleElementReferenceException in your isElementVisible() method. Sometimes, if the DOM changes during scrolling, this exception could occur.

Also, be sure to double-check your XPath for accuracy. If it's not accurately identifying the element, that could be a reason for your NoSuchElementException.

And finally, just a heads-up: Appium's mobile: scrollToElement might not be available in all scenarios. So, you might want to have a fallback plan, like using the swipe action to simulate scrolling.

Remember, automation can be a bit tricky sometimes, but you're doing great by digging into the details!